# Styling/binding when a FrameworkElement is a property for a ContentControl

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, styling, contentcontrol

I have created a smaller test project from a far complex actual project but the idea is the same. Both have the same problem.

I have two classes, A and B. A is a type of ContentControl and B is a type of FrameworkElement. A has a dependency property Bee (type of B). B has a dependency property Text (type of string). A's default value is null and B's default values is "B There!".

I'm using styling in my test window (Window.Resources) to set B's Text property to something else than the default value.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="local:B">
        <Setter Property="Text" Value="YO!!!"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

When I set A.Content to a new instance of B, everything works like a charm most likely because the system handles everything. I.e. when I change style setter's value in Visual Studio's designer, it changes the corresponding property value (B.Text). Data binding works fine, also.

```
<local:A.Content>
    <local:B/>
</local:A.Content>
```

What I actually need is below...

For reasons I cannot control I cannot use A.Content for this so I create a new B instance and set it to A.Bee property. In this case implicit styling and data context inheritance does not work. I.e. when I change style setter's value, nothing happens and data binding does not work either.

```
<local:A.Bee>
    <local:B/>
</local:A.Bee>
```

In A.Bee property value changed callback I use AddLogicalChild, AddVisualChild and data binding to put the B instance into the trees and make data binding work. I.e. when A.Bee is set, the below happens (simplified)...

```
private static void BeeChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    A instanceOfA = d as A;
    B newValue = e.NewValue as B;

    Binding b = new Binding("DataContext");
    b.Source = instanceOfA;

    BindingOperations.SetBinding(newValue, B.DataContextProperty, b);

    instanceOfA.AddLogicalChild(newValue);
    instanceOfA.AddVisualChild(newValue);
}
```

This fixes the data binding problem. Not sure if this is a correct way, but it works. Let me know if there's a better way. However, styling still does not work in Visual Studio's designer.

*How can I bind to styling values so that property values change when I change style setter's values in Visual Studio's designer?*

newValue has no style in its resources until AddLogicalChild is used so I think I'm on the right tracks but not quite there, yet...

If necessary, I can add a link to my project if someone wants to test/modify it.

---

Here's a link to the test solution (Visual Studio 2013): [FEStyleTesting](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-2zAiGODhiFRWhEX3pWbE5nb0k/view?usp=sharing)

---

In a nutshell, I want setting the A.Bee property with an instance of B class to work just like setting the A.Content property with an instance of B class. I.e. data context and styles are inherited to the instance of B class when using Visual Studio Designer.

---

[image: Debugging designer]

In the image, I'm debugging the designer and as you can see, the style setters can be found from resources after AddLogicalChild is called but for some reason the style isn't applied in designer... And there's a third setter for InstantietedElementViewNode property when in designer. I.e. it's not there in run-time. Maybe it's something the designer adds for every control... The first two setters are the ones defined in XAML (forgot to expand them for the picture).

---

Just to clarify, in the test application the idea is to use the message boxes for testing. I.e. I don't need the visual appearance to change (which it does when using the Content property). Just get the callbacks invoked when style setter values are changed in XAML.

---

Here are steps to test this problem:

1. Open the solution.
2. Make sure that no source tab pages are open.
3. Rebuild the solution just in case.
4. Open MainWindow.xaml (double-click it).
5. Click "Ok" button if message boxes appear.
6. Make sure that the first assignment under "These don't work" is uncommented and the other three are commented out. (Can't get source code in this list for some reason...)
7. Now change the value of the style setter for Text property to e.g. "YO2!!!".
8. A "TextChanged" message box should appear after editing the value (but it doesn't).

---

B is derived from ContentControl (and not from FrameworkElement) on purpose so that I could verify data binding and style inheritance when using the A.Content property. ContentControl is derived from FrameworkElement so the outcome should be the same. FrameworkElement is used in my larger project.

---

[image: Debugging style value change.]

While debugging the designer, I changed "YO!!!" to "YO2!!!" and then changed B.Color explicitly in XAML. Then in ColorChanged callback I took a look at B instance's resources and noticed that the value had changed accordingly. So styling values are updated when I change them in XAML but they don't change the property value for some reason (Text is still "YO!!!")... Hence, no callbacks invoked.

I wonder what might cause this...

---

I may have found a **possible solution**. I noticed that even though I called AddLogicalChild, A.LogicalChildren did not contain the B object. I then went through overridable methods and ran into overridable LogicalChildren property.

Here's my version:

```
protected override IEnumerator LogicalChildren
{
    get
    {
        List<object> list = new List<object>();

        while (base.LogicalChildren.MoveNext() == true)
        {
            try
            {
                list.Add(base.LogicalChildren.Current);
            }
            catch
            {
                // If Current fails, break.
                break;
            }
        }

        list.Add(Bee);

        return list.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Not sure if this is the "ultimate" solution but now my property changed callbacks are invoked every time I change style setter values. Well, live and learn... Better test this some more.

Comment: A.. A.Bee.. I lost the point before you even start explaining your attempted solution to the problem. Can you try to write using single sentence what doesn't work? *"How can I bind to styling values so that property values change when I change style setter's values in Visual Studio's designer"* - what is styling values? Do you want to control what happens in design time? Is it working at run-time? Start with [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post it here, add reasonable explanation (what you want and what happens instead).

Comment: Styling values are the values set to style setters in Window.Resources. Ask for the example project before starting to complain if you don't understand, thanks.

Comment: And yes, it is working run-time, hence I mentioned Visual Studio designer.

Comment: A download link added.

Comment: I've tried your test project. When commenting/uncommenting either of 4 assignements (one has mistake with `text`) I am getting 2-3 `MessageBox` messages in designer (`TextChanged` and `ColorChanged`). To me it seems like everything is working. VS 2015 community Update 3.

Comment: Please don't tell me it's a bug in Visual Studio... Just started to updated my 2015. I had Update 1 installed. Did you try changing style's Text property value multiple times and get the message box every time? I.e. from "YO!!!" to "YO2!!!" and back and forth...

Comment: Just making sure... The two assignments that use the A.Content property work but the two that use A.Bee property don't. I had the same problem with VS2015 Update 1 as with VS2013 Update 5 so hopefully Update 3 will fix this...

Comment: Nope, I'm having the same problem with Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, too. Maybe I'll add steps to test this problem...

Comment: A possible solution found...

Comment: You can [write an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/299295) then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to the problem is to override LogicalChildren property to include the nested object. This will also remove the need for BindingOperations to bind to DataContext. AddLogicalChild is still required. Not sure about AddVisualChild but better safe than sorry...